# tSQLt.ExceptException is not working with rollback transaction in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsqlt

Below is my code snippet of a test case for a stored procedure `my_proc` to check not null parameter passed to the stored procedure.

```
--faking required tables here

--set values of parameters to be passed
DECLARE @LINK_ID            INT = null -- required parameter which is passed null
          , @LINK_TYPE          VARCHAR(250) = 'GTN_ALERT_OPERATIONS'
          , @FILE_NAME          VARCHAR(250) = 'XML.png'
          , @FILE_SIZE          VARCHAR(250) = '2060'
          , @FILE_DATA          VARBINARY(MAX) = null
          , @FILE_TYPE          VARCHAR(10) = 'PNG'
          , @MODUKE_KEY         VARCHAR(20)  ='GTN'
          , @USER_ID            INT = 1
          , @ORGANIZATION_ID    INT = 1
          , @UPDATEDATE         datetime = getdate()    
          , @ERR_STATUS         SMALLINT = 0
          , @ERR_MSG            VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
          , @ERR_STATUS_EXPECTED SMALLINT = 2

EXEC tsqlt.ExpectException @ExpectedMessagePattern ='%Cannot insert the value NULL into column ''LINK_ID''%'

BEGIN TRY
        EXEC my_proc @LINK_ID = @LINK_ID, @LINK_TYPE = @LINK_TYPE, @FILE_NAME = @FILE_NAME, @FILE_SIZE = @FILE_SIZE
                           , @FILE_DATA = @FILE_DATA, @FILE_TYPE = @FILE_TYPE, @MODUKE_KEY = @MODUKE_KEY, @USER_ID = @USER_ID
                           , @ORGANIZATION_ID = @ORGANIZATION_ID, @ERR_STATUS = @ERR_STATUS OUT, @ERR_MSG = @ERR_MSG OUT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH 
        IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0
        begin
            BEGIN TRAN --reopen an transaction as it gave error due to rollack called in my_proc
        end
END CATCH
```

If here @LINK_ID is not nullable parameter so it should throw exception like

> Cannot insert null ..

as I have mentioned above. So here it works well and results as passed.

But even if I change some random message instead of "cannot insert null.." this test passes, which is ideally wrong. It should fail.

It happens due to internal transaction used in `my_proc`, which executes rollback tran on error.

Please suggest a possible solution.

Comment: For starters, you cannot "reopen" a transaction. But if your stored procedure is designed to manage the work it does in a transaction it starts, you should not expect to override that logic.  But your problem description doesn't mean much without knowing what your 2 stored procedures actually do - "change some random message" doesn't mean much to your reader nor why that action "should be failed".

Comment: @SMor Given code above is a tsqlt test case stored procedure, which runs in transaction on its own. So when i call my_proc (procedure for which this outer test case procedure is written), which has its own begin - commit/rollback inside my_proc. so when an error occurred inside my_proc it execute rollback and so it rolls back main transaction in which outer test case is running. due to that i had to reopen in catch block above. this is not an ideal solution i know that. So I am looking for better solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got answer to my problem which will helpful for tsqlt test case and normal nested transactions procedures

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/82697/213662

Comment: Were you able to have a stored procedure that performs a ROLLBACK and have it tested without erroring out in tSQLt? If yes I would very much like to see some sample code, but at this point I don't really think it is possible.

Comment: @pygri do not have such an example code as of now but you can make change to your stored procedure that performs a ROLLBACK using a flag if it is 0. That flag should be set in the beginning to 1 only if there is already an open transaction available. Hope this helps.

Comment: yes if one does not perform the ROLLBACK, then indeed you can test the routine. But not if you want to perform a COMMIT or ROLLBACK and test that it worked as expected. I guess that's an inherent limitation of the lack of support for nested transactions in SQL server.

Answer (score 3):

If your code rolls back the tSQLt transaction, all bets are off (so to speak).
tSQLt maintains a lot of metadata in tables that will be affected by a forced rollback.

tSQLt will correctly error out the test if you leave a transaction that "died" as is (as you noted in your comment). But if you recreate a new transaction it will get in an undocumented state and might pass or fail.

The error you're trying to hide by "reopening" the transaction is telling you that your architecture has a problem:

In general, a stored procedure should never rollback a transaction that it didn't open. More information on that you can find here: [How to rollback in procedures](https://sqlity.net/en/585/how-to-rollback-in-procedures/)

As a side note: You are currently "eating" the exception in your `TRY...CATCH`. So tSQLt will never get to see it, even if you removed the `ROLLBACK`.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I know above reopening transaction is not a right solution but tried as i found it somewhere on stackoverflow itself. I have read your blog too where you have written about partial rollback and save point. But my_proc is called from other proc too so i cant put savepoint in my_proc. I also saw that my_proc rollback emptied #Exception table. thats the reason it shows passed with any message in ExceptException method, Can you suggest where should i put savepoint in this case?

Comment: I tried another way of making transaction inside my_proc conditional based on from where its being called. if its being called from tSQLt test then it will use transaction inside my_proc. Please suggest if it can have any other side effects. Also "

If your code rolls back the tSQLt transaction, all bets are off (so to speak). tSQLt maintains a lot of metadata in tables that will be affected by a forced rollback.

tSQLt will correctly fail the test if you leave a transaction that "died" - Here test cases results as Errored with transaction count mismatch error. Not returning Expected Error

Comment: Why do you think that your proc being called from another prof prevents the use of safepoints? 
 // 
“Correctly fail the test” - I misspoke. Correctly indicate that the situation is broken. In other words not silently pass.

Comment: We have structure build of nested procs like one proc calls many procs and each proc has transactions. so if any one proc failed then it should rollback main proc itself. so if i put save point in any such child proc then it would work for tSQLt test case but would not work when its being called from other main proc. Thats why i am bit hesitant to use save point. Please correct me if i am wrong.